# Problem with loading p5.js sketch in Semplice (WordPress theme)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, p5.js

I'm working on a website with the WordPress theme "Semplice" and I am experiencing issues with running a p5.js sketch. The sketch is meant to display an interactive line that responds to mouse movement, but it doesn't appear to be running. I'm using the custom JavaScript feature and code modules provided by Semplice to implement this.

I am currently working on a website using the WordPress theme "Semplice". I'm trying to implement a p5.js sketch using Semplice's custom JavaScript feature and code modules, but I'm encountering issues.

I've managed to successfully load the p5.js library globally using the custom JavaScript feature. To confirm that it was loading correctly, I added an alert in the library callback. This alert ("p5.js has loaded") is being displayed as expected.

The issue arises when I try to add my p5.js sketch to a code module on a page. The sketch, which is an interactive line that reacts to the mouse's position, does not seem to run. Here is the code for the sketch:

```
let maxDistance = 100;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  for (let i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    points[i] = height / 2;
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  stroke(0);

  for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    points[i] = lerp(points[i], height / 2, 0.05);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    let distance = dist(mouseX, mouseY, i, points[i]);
    if (distance < maxDistance) {
      let m = map(distance, 0, maxDistance, 1, 0);
      points[i] = lerp(points[i], mouseY, m * 0.05);
    }
  }

  noFill();
  beginShape();
  for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    vertex(i, points[i]);
  }
  endShape();
}
```

To troubleshoot the issue, I tried running a simple static circle sketch to see if the problem might be specific to my original code. Unfortunately, this simple sketch also didn't run.

Can anyone help me understand why this might be happening and how I can get my p5.js sketch running.